# Using Google Maps with JQuery by Addresses instead Latitudes and Longitudes

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Until today I've working with GMaps like this:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(latitude, longitude), 15);
        map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(latitude, longitude)));
        map.setUIToDefault();
```

However, now I need to set the center and add the overlay by a full address (string), instead of using latitude and longitude.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Found it.

This is the way if someone is interested:

JS:

```
function initializate() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        var center = new GLatLng(48.89364, 2.33739);
        map.setCenter(center, 15);
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        var marker = new GMarker(center, {
            draggable: true
        });
        map.addOverlay(marker);

    }
}

function showAddress(address) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(
            address,
            function(point) {
                if (!point) {
                    alert(address + " not found");
                } else {
                    map.clearOverlays()
                    map.setCenter(point, 16);
                    var marker = new GMarker(point, {
                        draggable: false
                    });
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                }
            }
            );
    }
}
```

Then I just call:

```
initializate();
showAddress($(".hotel_location").html()); //Addres as a string
```

And that's it =)